# Any way to get a kml file of city boundaries?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I noticed on google maps there's a red outline of city limits.

Is there any way to get a KML file of the city limits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update** fixed stale link

US Cities for 2019 and later can be found here

https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/cartographic-boundary.html

I was incidentally looking for the same thing. Census link was the number one result, this article was 4th on the list. Saw it had no answer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome!   I found it and should have updated.  Its good to have an answer for others. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Is the Place kml file for state is considered as US cities kml data ?